# Portable Native Client (PNaCl) - Visual Studio 2012 is crashing when debugging starts

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, google-nativeclient

When I try to debug my PNaCl application with Visual Studio 2012 Pro, it crashses very often.

1. Run "Local Windows Debugger" in configuration Debug\PNaCl.
2. Chrome launches, as well as gdb console.
3. At this point Visual Studio crashes, but not always - sometimes everything is working fine...

Here are some important details from the Windows Event Log Viewer:

```
Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 11.0.61030.0, time stamp: 0x5270a974
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.18409, time stamp: 0x53159a86
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x0000c42d
Faulting process id: 0x904


Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
```

I am using pepper_39 SDK with vs_addin revision 1578. Windows 7 64-bit.

Any help will be much appreciated.